# how to convert a string received from jquery to c# dynamic object?

Tags: c#, jquery

how can i convert a string which is a json object to dynamic in my c# WEBMETHOD..so that i can use it retrieve data.

example 
    my ajax call

```
 function do_save_data()
    {
      $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"../mymethods/test.aspx/SaveUser",
         data:"{'profile':'"+objrecieved+"'}",
         contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success:function(msg){}
      });

} 



[WebMethod]
public void save data(object profile)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer _myserliaser=new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic data=(dynamic)_myserliaser.DeseralizeObject(profile);

    //problem here is it is taking it as a string.hence when it try
    string name=data.name.ToString();
    //error 'string' does not contain a definition for 'name'



}
```

can anyone please tell me how to handle object that comes from ajax call as string and put it into dynamic and get its details
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "objrecieved" meant to look like (should be "received" by the way, if you want to avoid later confusion... trust me on this one!), and is it available in scope? I don't see it available in your sample, but it might be a brief sample that neglects it.

Comment: hi greg, thanks for the response, in the code snippet "objreceived" is the string that i prepared before my ajax call...thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScriptSerializer seralizes JSON string to a Dictionary, you can't just cast it to dynamic, otherwise you lose the properties, your best bet is to convert the dictionary to an ExpandoObject which you can easily cast to dynamic.
Here's an extension method to do so:

```
public static class JavaScriptSerializerExtension
{
    public static dynamic DeserializeDynamic(this JavaScriptSerializer serializer, string value)
    {
        var dic = serializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(value);
        return ToExpando(dic);
    }

    private static ExpandoObject ToExpando(IDictionary<string, object> dic)
    {
        var expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

        foreach (var item in dic)
        {
            var prop = item.Value as IDictionary<string, object>;
            expando.Add(item.Key, prop == null ? item.Value : ToExpando(prop));
        }

        return (ExpandoObject)expando;
    }
}
```

you can use DeserializeDynamic extension method of the JavaScriptSerializer object to deserialize to dynamic

Comment: thanks Nazeri, the above code snippet works thanks once again.. i was banging my head over this for over one day.. i didn't know why the string is being converted to Dictionary till this answer..